# Send newsletter in both HTML and TXT format in one email

Tags: html, newsletter, spam-prevention

I'm testing my newsletter in terms of recognition by spam filters. I see some errors. One of them is **BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts**. I read that this is because I only have HTML format so I prepared something like this:

```
<html>
    <title>Newsletter 03/2013</title>
    <body>
    <p>Newsletter content for this month</p>
    </body>
<html>
Newsletter content for this month
```

But this did not resolve my problem.. Maybe you can suggest me how to avoid this error? Also I found other "spam-kind" errors.

BODY: PL_DISCOUNT
BODY: PL_DISCOUNT
1.0 BODY: PL_NEW_OFFER
0.5 URI: URI hostname has long non-vowel sequence
1.1 BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
2.2 HTML_TITLE_SUBJ_DIFF

Any advices?

Emails are sending by web-platform.

Comment: What are you using to send the mail? Sending plain text as well as HTML isn't just a case of putting the text after the HTML. How you do it depends on what you're sending it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails that contain a text and HTML version are actually taking advantange of the [multipart/alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Alternative) MIME subtype. This is part of the structure of raw email data that you usually don't have to deal with. It would be a feature of an email sending library or application to define the content of the text and HTML parts, which can actually be completely different if you wish.